# AndroidAnnotations restClient get responsebody of 404 error

Tags: android, spring, android-annotations

I am doing an API call but the API sends back an error with the status code 404. How can I get the response of the API so I can see what the exact error is?

The error I am getting is:

```
08-12 09:52:05.977  11040-11221/eu.app W/RestTemplate﹕ POST request for "http://hidden-api-url.com" resulted in 404 (Not Found); invoking error handler
08-12 09:52:09.051  11040-11221/eu.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-5-thread-3
    Process: eu.app, PID: 11040
    org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 404 Not Found
```

Comment: the exact error is the object is not found (http 404), please review your urls. Also, read about the codes http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html the 404 is just you´ve misspeled something or so in the url

Comment: the url is working, not all the calls return an 404 error but the api returns 404 errors when an ID is not found or other not found issues.

Comment: ok, then I´m completelly right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I caught the `HttpClientErrorException` and got the response with `getResponseBodyAsString();`.

```
    try {
        restClient.restCall(data);
    } catch (HttpClientErrorException e) {
        Log.d("Response",e.getResponseBodyAsString());
    }
```

Comment: You could also use an error handler. https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Rest-API#error-handler

Comment: Forgot to do that. Thanks!